# Git smudge filter applies wrong information

Tags: git

I have to set up keyword substitution with Git. According to the recommendations of [Keyword Expansion](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes) and [Filter](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_filter) and the hints of [Martin Turon](https://github.com/turon/git-rcs-keywords), I wrote a `.git_filters/keywords-smudge.sh` and a `.git_filters/keywords-clean.sh` as filters in bash:

**keywords-smudge.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

# Replace the keywords after the checkout.
# This script is executed in streaming mode:
# keywords-smudge.sh file.c < file.c

set -e

# Capture the argument:
filename=$1

# Compute the keyword values:
repository=$(git config --get remote.origin.url)
repository=${repository%.git/}
#
branch=$(git branch --show-current)
#
repo_root=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)
repo_root=${repo_root/C://c}
parent=$(dirname $repo_root)
filepath=$(realpath --relative-to=$parent $filename)
#
log=$(git log -- $filename | head -n 4)
hash=$(echo $log | sed 's/commit \([a-z0-9]*\) .*/\1/')
author=$(echo $log | sed 's/.*Author: \(.*\) <.*/\1/')
date=$(echo $log | sed 's/.*Date: \(.*\) +.*/\1/')

# Replace the keywords with their value:
sed \
  -e 's#\$Repository\$#\$Repository: '"$repository"' \$#' \
  -e 's#\$Branch\$#\$Branch: '"$branch"' \$#' \
  -e 's#\$File\$#\$File: '"$filepath"' \$#' \
  -e 's/\$Hash\$/\$Hash: '"$hash"' \$/' \
  -e 's/\$Author\$/\$Author: '"$author"' \$/' \
  -e 's/\$Date\$/\$Date: '"$date"' \$/'
```

**keywords-clean.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

# Reset the keywords before staging the file.
# This script is executed in streaming mode:
# keywords-clean.sh < file.c

set -e

# Remove the keyword values:
sed \
  -e 's/\$Repository[^\$]*\$/\$Repository\$/' \
  -e 's/\$Branch[^\$]*\$/\$Branch\$/' \
  -e 's/\$File[^\$]*\$/\$File\$/' \
  -e 's/\$Hash[^\$]*\$/\$Hash\$/' \
  -e 's/\$Author[^\$]*\$/\$Author\$/' \
  -e 's/\$Date[^\$]*\$/\$Date\$/'
```

I configured (locally) my repository to use them:

```
[filter "keywords"]
    smudge = .git_filters/keywords-smudge.sh %f
    clean = .git_filters/keywords-clean.sh
```

... and created the `.gitattributes` file containing:

```
*.h filter=keywords
*.c filter=keywords
```

When I manually execute the scripts, they give the expected result:

```
// $Branch: work $
// $File: sandbox/file1.h $
// $Hash: 0f3af9f30a9c9978322f8e0ee175625e435283da $
// $Date: Tue Dec 14 11:42:42 2021 $
```

Also when I `rm file1.h; git checkout file1.h`. So I suppose, my word is OK so far.

What I then expect, is that the information added in the file by the *smudge* filter reflect the last commit of that file **on the branch where I go with a checkout**. And it does not run this way. As illustrated in the `git log --graph` below, I have two branches, *develop* and *work*, starting at the same commit. The filter files are available on both. On each of them, I committed a change in my `file1.h`.

```
* 9b27ded (HEAD -> develop) Changed.
| * 0f3af9f (work) Changed.
|/
* 478bc4c (origin/develop) Removed blabla.
```

When I execute `checkout work`, the file is completed with the commit information of the `develop` branch, and when I execute `checkout develop`, the file is completed with the commit information of the `work` branch.
Is that normal? Is my expectation feasible?

Comment: You can get all this information on the fly, cheaply enough as a one-off but going through all these gyrations for every file on every checkout is Ministry-of-Silly-Walks stuff. If you want it done for some external tooling it's easy enough to add it to your deployment chain, where it can be done *much* more efficiently and just once. Add some context to your question, what tools are using this info and  what they're trying to achieve with it, and maybe you can get some help with that.

Comment: @jthill: I agree with you that this mechanism is a lot of manipulations. I already remarked its cost in time during a checkout. My personal opinion is that this information is useless in the file itself: the interface to any version control system is sufficient to get it. But I'm asked to provide such a functionality... :-(.
Thanks however for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> branch=$(git branch --show-current)
> ```

Don't do this.

The smudge filter runs *before* the checkout finishes.  The branch name, if any—remember that "detached HEAD" commits have no branch name—changes *last*, **after** all files have been updated in the index and working tree.  So you'll always have the wrong information here.

Branch *names*, in Git, are useless.  Commit hash IDs are the only reliable values (but unfortunately you can't get that either, for the same reason you can't get the branch name).

The hash ID of the *file* isn't available the way you're doing it either, for similar reasons; I'm not sure if you can `git rev-parse` the index copy of the file at this point as the index entry might not be written out yet.  This one is a bit more insidious since the method you're using is likely to work for most files, which will mostly be the same in most commits!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your technical explanation! I understand now what I get... and that it is not possible to achieve my goal this way. I might look at the Git hooks, that I have yet to discover.